# Decide if the given endomorphism $F:V\rightarrow V$ is normal

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, multilinear-algebra, bilinear-form

> Decide if the given endomorphism $F:V\rightarrow V$ is normal
>
> Let $V := \mathbb{C}[x]_{\leq 2}$ with $ \langle g,h\rangle := \int_{-1}^{1}g(x)\overline{h(x)}dx$ and $F$ given by the derivative $F(g):=g'$

I would love to get some tipps on how to solve this one.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**Tip:** Your operator satisfies $F^3 = 0$ so $F$ is nilpotent. When can a nilpotent operator be normal?

Comment: when it satisfies f* x f = f x f* right? But how do u apply this here? Would you just create the matrix corresponding to the endomorphism with the basis 1,x,x^2 and then take the conjugate transpose of it and check the criteria?